# Index routes in Scala Play Framework 2.5.x

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I am super new to the Play Framework and just started my first experiences with the [play-scala-rest-api-example](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-rest-api-example). I copied the post package as a new user package, added the `UserRouter` to the routes and appended the `UserRepository` to the Module configurations.

Everything works fine, it's just that I get an 404 error when visiting `/v1/users`. Only `/v1/users/` works. For posts both with and without the *slash* at the end call the index route. I didn't change anything but renaming the classes and objects. Like I said I just started to play around with the framework and possibly it is something super trivial.

Here the routes file:

```
GET        /                    controllers.HomeController.index

->         /v1/posts            api.post.PostRouter
->         /v1/users            api.user.UserRouter

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

`

Comment: According to play docs "You can tell the routes file to use a different router under a specific prefix by using “->” followed by the given prefix: ->" So why are you using -> and not simply repeat the GET /v1/posts GET /v1/etc?

Comment: I expect the error to be in your user router. Have you paid attention to the prefix value stored in there ?

Comment: @OlivierSamyn, I just copied the router. The prefix is `/v1/users` and the routes look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was missing. So for any else using [this tutorial](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-rest-api-example) and facing the same problem. You have to add your custom prefix to the `app/RequestHandler.scala` `isREST()` method. So the `handlerForRequest` method automatically adds a trailing slash at the end.

```
private def isREST(request: RequestHeader) = {
    request.uri match {
        case uri: String if uri.contains("post") => true
        case uri: String if uri.contains("user") => true
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

or

```
private def isREST(request: RequestHeader) = {
    request.uri match {
        case uri: String if uri.contains("post") | uri.contains("user") => true
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file should be

```
GET        /                    controllers.HomeController.index

GET         /v1/posts            api.post.PostRouter
GET         /v1/users            api.user.UserRouter

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The -> symbol is for some especial cases that probably you do not need right now.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting

Comment: I wanted to split my routes in different Router. So the `PostRouter`and `UserRouter` accept multiple routes. For example `GET / #index` `POST / #new` or `GET /:id #show` etc. I wander if I can only use the `->` once and have to combine the router in one file